# Extracting the index of frame selected by ffmpeg thumbnail filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I use the following command for extracting the representative frame out of every 10 frames from the  video.

> ffmpeg -i input.avi -r 10 -vf thumbnail=10 -vsync 0 ./Output/%06d.png

If i get the 4th frame selected from 10-20th frames, i want to know the 2nd frame selected was 24th in the original one.

Right now the output is continuous 1,2,3.. n.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 ffmpeg -i input.avi -vf thumbnail=10 -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 ./Output/%06d.png
```

You'll need ffmpeg 4.0 or later.